How to generate CEM from vue customElement
I am trying to create a webcomponent library based on vue component using defineCustomElement.
This is my test component
// Test.ce.vue
    <template>
      <button @click="onClick">{{ label }}</button>
    </template>

    <script>
    /**
    * custom button.
    *
    * @attr {string} label - label.
    * @event click - event trigger on click.
    */
    export default {
      props: {
        /** label of the button */
        label: {
          type: String,
          required: true,
        },
      },
      methods: {
        onClick() {
          this.$emit("click");
        },
      },
    };
    </script>

    <style>
    button {
      padding: 10px;
      font-size: 16px;
      cursor: pointer;
    }
    </style>

this is the index.ts allowing to create the custom element
    import { defineCustomElement } from "vue";
    import Test from "./Test.ce.vue";

    export const TestCE  = defineCustomElement<InstanceType<typeof Test>>(Test);
    customElements.define("xl-test", TestCE  );

and this is the vite.config.ts I am using

    import alias from "./alias";

    import { defineConfig } from "vite";
    import vue from "@vitejs/plugin-vue";
    import dts from 'vite-plugin-dts';

    // Vite for storybook
    export default defineConfig({
      plugins: [
        dts(),
        vue({
          customElement: true,
        }),
      ],
      build: {
        lib: {
          entry: __dirname + "/src/index.ts",
          name: "lib-components",
          formats: ['es'],
          // the proper extensions will be added
          fileName: "lib-components",
        },
        sourcemap: true,
        // Reduce bloat from legacy polyfills.
        target: 'esnext',
        // Leave minification up to applications.
        minify: false,
      }
    });

All of this is inside a node module name lib-components and I would like to use this one in another project even without vueJs on this new project and be helped about the new tag <xl-test>
I would love to have the Vscode ide helping me about the props label.
I did the job about the Jsdoc type but I am stuck now.
I had a look on @custom-elements-manifest/analyzer to try to generate the custom-elements.json based on the generated lib but the content is always empty
   {
     "schemaVersion": "1.0.0",
     "readme": "",
     "modules": []
   }

If anyone could helps :)
